# ng-repeat multiple $index

Tags: angularjs

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
     var personas = { 
       { persona1: { hijos: [1,2,3]}}, 
       { persona2: { hijos: [2,2,3]}}, 
       { persona1: { hijos: [1,2,3]}} 
    }

    <div>
        <div ng-repeat="(key, hijos) in personas">
        <label class="" style="width: 300px">{{key}}</label>

        <div ng-repeat="hij in hijos track by $index">
            <label style="width: 110px;">{{hij | number:2}}</label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Pero en consola estoy obteniendo  [ngRepeat:dupes], el problema esta en que en el primero hay algun repetido y tengo que poner a cada ng-repeat un $index, pero no se puede

Comment: Podrías incluir el arreglo que estas repitiendo?

Comment: algo asi seria el arreglo

Comment: pero **personas** es un `Objeto`, no tienes posibilidad de cambiarlo a un arreglo?

Answer (score 0):

A tu objeto le sobran unas `{}`, debería ser así:

```
var personas = { 
   persona1: { hijos: [1,2,3]}, 
   persona2: { hijos: [2,2,3]}, 
   persona1: { hijos: [1,2,3]} 
};
```

Y el marcado sería más bien así:

```
<div>
    <div ng-repeat="(key, persona) in personas">
    <label style="width: 300px">{{ key }}</label>

    <div ng-repeat="hijo in persona.hijos">
        <label style="width: 110px;">{{ hijo | number:2 }}</label>
    </div>
</div>
```